# SQL Stored Procedure shows blank report

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I am trying to create a Crystal Report within VS2015 but I am having issues with a stored procedure. When I run my report without a stored procedure it gets all the data required and all the groups and formulas work fine. Below is my main SQL code.

```
SELECT type, description, hire_status, fleet_no, location, date_starting, time_finishing, date_finishing, type, week_number, changes
FROM   XXXXXX INNER JOIN XXXXXX ON fleet_no= XXXXXX.fleet_no
WHERE  week_number= @weekNo
```

When I try and add a stored procedure to the report I only get a blank report, I lose all the data from the report. The stored procedure is as follows:

```
USE [xxxxxx]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Procedure [XXXXXXX].[getCurrentLocation] 
@fleet varchar(50) = NULL
AS 
Begin
SELECT TOP 1 (dbo.tbl_job_planning.location)
    FROM   dbo.tbl_job_planning
    WHERE  (fleet_no = @fleet) AND (date_starting <= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) / 7, 5))
    ORDER BY date_starting DESC
end;
```

I pass the parameter to this stored procedure in the record selection. 
I want the stored procedure to display a location on each line of the report. When I run the report with just the stored procedure I only get 1 value returned and not a value for each item in the report which is what I need.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: if you need all records then dont take top1 remove that and just take the database column.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting 1 value back because you are specifying
 `SELECT TOP 1 (dbo.tbl_job_planning.location)`. Just remove `TOP 1` or set the `1` to however many results you want it limited to , but certainly not one as you specified

Comment: All i want the stored procedure to do is return a single latest (top1) value for each record in the report. for example: If i have a report that returns address values: Name, D.O.B, Address, "Latest previous address", postcode etc. I want my stored procedure to return the "Latest previous address" for each person in my dataset in the report. i hope that makes sense.

Comment: @John if that is the requirement then your query doesn't work...you need to manipulate in crystal report... can you explain how your data looks like.

Comment: Ok i will try: I need it to show FleetNo, Description, finishdate, finishtime, hire_status, "Previous location" (this is the bit i am trying to do via stored procedure). I need to do this for every record that matches my parameters (i have two). Because i am matching parameters the sql statement does not return all the data from tables only what matches. This does not include the "previous location" as it does not fall in the parameters

Comment: I suggest building your tables using sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ and then we can help from there.

If we can see your table structure we can help identify any issues that may cause you from getting the results you are trying to retrieve